# Dismiss a modal viewController with push/pop animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

when presenting:

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
animation.delegate=self;
animation.duration=0.3;
animation.type=kCATransitionMoveIn;
animation.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;

UIViewController13 *vc = [[UIViewController13 alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
[vc.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

but I don't know how to customize the dismiss animation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956981/how-to-dismiss-a-modal-vc-with-fade-out-animation

Comment: i think you can't do this i face same probalam but i can't

Comment: When I was asking the same question I ended up using `UINavigationController` and not messing up with iOS default behaviour. There is a fundamental difference between a modal view and an ordinary one that's been pushed to the Navigation stack. Changing it seems quite alogical.

Comment: fade effect is easy, but push should be a different way @RanjuPatel

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it:

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
animation.delegate=self;
animation.duration=0.3;
animation.type=kCATransitionMoveIn;
animation.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;

UIViewController13 *vc = [[UIViewController13 alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
[self.view insertSubview:vc.view atIndex:0];  //line we add
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"]; //we edit
```