# Change dismissViewControllerAnimated's animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a method

```
- (void) swipeRight
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Which I am using to dismiss the view controller when the user swipes right. 
I dont really like the animation that apple provides when you dismiss the view controller (page goes down) and I want to change it to a different one that apple provides, while still using the dismissViewControllerAnimated method.
Can anyone help me change this?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956981/how-to-dismiss-a-modal-vc-with-fade-out-animation

Comment: that answer only applies on ios6 and down

Answer (score 3):

For @Tomaž Stoiljkovič (and anyone interested in **Swift 4**)

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop

    navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this just before your dismiss:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.3;
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
```

Then set animated:NO

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

-- More transition types you can try:

```
kCATransitionFade;
kCATransitionMoveIn;
kCATransitionPush;
kCATransitionReveal;
```

Comment: I'm not using a navigationcontroller i'm doing everything manually in this case, so thats not working for me. Can u update it? thanks =)

Comment: Not sure, you can try self.view.layer... instead of self.navigationController.view.layer

Comment: What about swift version of this?